# React Native useEffect rerenders with initial states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

In the code below, when the app loads initially "Location changed offline!" is logged every time the location updates. When `online` is set to true with a TouchableOpacity, the message logged to the console looks like this:

```
 LOG  true
 LOG  attempting to update location...
 LOG  Location updated in real-time!
 LOG  false
 LOG  Location changed offline!
 LOG  true
 LOG  attempting to update location...
 LOG  true
 LOG  attempting to update location...
 LOG  Location updated in real-time!
```

For some reason it's randomly changing the state of `online` back to false, thus causing the "Location changed offline!" to be logged. What could be causing this?

```
  const [online, setOnline] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.watchPosition(
      position => {
        console.log(online);
        if (online) {
          console.log('attempting to update location...');
          const payload = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
            id: 1,
          };

          axios
            .post('http://localhost:3000/location/update', payload)
            .then(res => {
              if (res.status === 200) {
                console.log('Location updated in real-time!');
                return;
              }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response));
        } else {
          console.log('Location changed offline!');
        }
      },
      err => console.log(err.response)
    );
  }, [online]);
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you use setOnline to set the value for online. 

Try to add that that after your axios call. 

And I would also use Async Await pattern instead of .then chain.

Comment: @shaileshgavathe changing `online` inside the effect hook will lead to an infinite loop

Comment: it won't , also add your dependency setOnline part of the useEffect. 

I am guessing the setOnline is being called somewhere else.

Comment: @shaileshgavathe it most certainly will. And you never need to pass state setters into an effect hook's dependencies

Comment: setOnline is being called in a TouchableOpacity. Changing the state inside useEffect will trigger an infinite loop because the component will rerender every time setState is called.

Comment: yeah @Phil , I do see this could run into infinite loop. The dependency needs to be empty []. 


  useEffect(() => {
    const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(
      pos => {
        setError("");
        setPosition({
          latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
          longitude: pos.coords.longitude
        });
      },
      e => setError(e.message)
    );
    return () => Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
  }, []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you add a new *watcher* every time `online` changes that captures the current value forever.

Adding subscriptions (like `Geolocation.watchPosition()`) within an effect hook should always be removed in the cleanup function.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition(async (position) => {
    console.log("online?", online);
    if (online) {
      console.log("attempting to update location...");
      const payload = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
        id: 1,
      };

      try {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/location/update", payload);

        // no need to check the response status
        console.log("Location updated in real-time!");
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err.toJSON()); // Axios helper, much nicer to look at
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Location changed offline!");
    }
  }, console.error);

  // return a cleanup function
  return () => {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
  };
}, [online]);
```

See https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/geolocation#clearwatch